# How to remove program that does not appear in Programs and Features?

Tags: windows, uninstall

I'm trying to install Windows 7.  During the install, it tells me that I need to uninstall the Kapersky Anti-Virus program.  However, Kapersky does not show up in Programs and Features.

How do I remove Kapersky?  I am running 64 bit Vista Ultimate so I cannot use Revo.

Answer (score 4):

Taking it that you are still on board with XP or Vista, get a program from www.cnet.com, it's free:

- [CCleaner](http://download.cnet.com/ccleaner/)
- [REVO Uninstaller](http://download.cnet.com/Revo-Uninstaller/3000-2096_4-10687648.html)

I expect one of these will help.

Comment: +1 for Revo, very awesome program. But CCleaner is useful too.

Comment: The poster states that Revo is not compatible with 64-bit systems, and cnet concurs. So -1 for that but +1 for CCleaner!

Comment: I was told by the Revo developer that there will be a release in December that will be W7 64bit compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Use Kaspersky's uninstaller from [Uninstall Kaspersky](http://support.kaspersky.com/downloads/products2009/kavremover9.zip)

Or you can use [AppRemover](http://www.appremover.com/)

Comment: Unfortunately, neither Kaspersky's uninstaller nor AppRemover detect Kaspersky.  Hence, neither can uninstall.

Comment: Kaspersky has individual removers for different versions, e.g. 2009 and 2010.  Try the one you didn't try already.

Answer (score 2):

Have you been into your C drive folders and looked for Kaspersky?  If not, do so.
You may also have to enter the computer's registry and delete other related files.
If you venture into the registry, **tread lightly** or have someone who is competent help you do this.  It's too easy to brick your  machine by deleting the wrong thing in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just planning to upgrade to 7, and if you have a major-manufacturer PC (e.g. Dell or HP), back up your data then use the "recovery disk" or "recovery partition" to return to plain-vanilla Windows XP/Vista, then install 7 over that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-installing it (over top and replacing whatever files) and then uninstalling it that way ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which Kaspersky, AppRemover detects it.
http://www.appremover.com/supported-applications
It can also do heuristic removal for apps not fully supported.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading a bit between the lines and I take it you have a Windows 7 Upgrade version?  It is actually possible to perform a FULL INSTALL using a Windows 7 Upgrade, giving you a cleaner OS than upgrading from your old OS.

[Full Install using an Upgrade version of Windows 7](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/clean-install-of-windows-7-from-a-windows-7/9d57b9f2-bf9b-4244-8fdf-edd777ba4489?auth=1)

In short, you skip the CD-Key entry, and you upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 7... takes longer but it will be a cleaner install.