# any tools to uninstall a software which cannot be uninstall from control panel

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove program that does not appear in Programs and Features?](https://superuser.com/questions/63930/how-to-remove-program-that-does-not-appear-in-programs-and-features)

Any tools which can uninstall software whihc cannot be uninstalled from control panel?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Tune Up Utilities](http://www.tune-up.com/), it has many cleaning and uninstalling tools