# Freeware Uninstaller Software

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Alternatives to Revo Uninstaller?](https://superuser.com/questions/122084/alternatives-to-revo-uninstaller)
>   [any tools to uninstall a software which cannot be uninstall from control panel](https://superuser.com/questions/276420/any-tools-to-uninstall-a-software-which-cannot-be-uninstall-from-control-panel)
>   [How to remove program that does not appear in Programs and Features?](https://superuser.com/questions/63930/how-to-remove-program-that-does-not-appear-in-programs-and-features)

Can someone recommended good uninstall software utilities that are freeware?

I need the one that could clean the remaining of the software that is uninstalled.

Thanks!

Comment: Also see - http://superuser.com/questions/276420/any-tools-to-uninstall-a-software-which-cannot-be-uninstall-from-control-panel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/builds). The one tool for cleaning all sorts unwanted entries from your machine. It also has a built in uninstaller under it's 'Tools' section.
[image]

Comment: +1 for CCleaner as I didn't realise it did uninstallation as well.

Comment: It uninstall the sameway as windows does.CC doesn't do anything new as far as uninstallation goes.

Answer (score 0):

[Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) should be all you need. Avalible in both freeware and paid versions, as well as a portable installer.

Comment: That's the only one I've needed so I'm not aware of any others. What is it you need to get rid of?

Answer (score 0):

I like Glarys,
under the Modules tab in the Clean up & Repair Option the Uninstall Manager gives a good, easy to use cleanup with both free and paid for versions. It also comes with other helpful software.
[This is the free version](http://www.glarysoft.com/products/utilities/glary-utilities/download/?ref=update%22This%20is%20the%20free%20version%22) 
[image: glarys modules]

A list of other Uninstallers (with reviews)  specializing  in anti-virus cleanup,  registry cleaners, etc,
can be found at [C Net](http://download.cnet.com/windows/uninstallers/?tag=mncol;sort&rpp=30&sort=)   which should help you with your selection.