# How to uninstall software that doesn't appear in Programs and Features as well as in uninstall softwares?

Tags: windows-7, windows, uninstall

I have in my Windows 7 64 bit a LabCenter Electronics' Proteus 7.7 Professional I would like to uninstall. Unfortunately the installation didn't give any uninstall executable file and I can't find the proper "uninstall icon" in Programs and Features (I suppose this is a consequence of the first fact). Following [this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/63930/how-to-remove-program-that-does-not-appear-in-programs-and-features), I tried to do it by using some uninstall tool, testing with *Advanced Uninstaller PRO* and the *REVO Uninstaller* suggested in that question, but both of them are unable to notice the presence of Proteus in my computer. I also did some research on this specific case on Google and found [this](http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/Proteus-7-Professional-37562-program.aspx), [this](http://www.advanceduninstaller.com/Proteus-7-Professional-bf591b68880c36592a45a89249e8b11c-application.htm) and [this](http://www.advanceduninstaller.com/Proteus-7-Professional-7ea7e5d5291a447d26324b55d5ff0eb0-application.htm) links which essentially tell that I should remove Proteus using the command line

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{13C4E8F0-B747-4C7C-9090-884832F9F90A}\setup.exe -runfromtemp -l0x0009 -removeonly
```

Unfortunately I also don't have the folder named `{13C4E8F0-B747-4C7C-9090-884832F9F90A}` in the InstallShield Installation Information folder, so I can't run this command either.

So what are my options for this case? Should I just manually remove the folder? But wouldn't that lead to problems (such as lots of trash in the registry with no guarantee that will be cleaned in the next registry clean-up)? And what about the folder in the Start Menu?

**EDIT**

I also tried removing it by running the installer and seeing if it had an option such as "modify/remove", but it didn't (and it didn't notice the presence of Proteus as well).

Comment: Have you tried using System Restore to revert back to a point prior to having installed the unwanted program?

Comment: This is the reason I don't like "uninstall" programs, they really do more harm, then good.

Comment: Are you running as administrator? Have you enabled the option to "show hidden files?"  Check out your `services`, startup programs **and** `scheduled tasks`. It could still be running in the background which may be preventing complete installation. For the record Revo Uninstaller has never done me wrong, it may not notice **every** program but that's a different conversation.

Comment: Have you tried obtaining the original installer to see if it has a "modify/remove" option when it runs?

Comment: run the installer of the tool, sometimes they detect that it is installed and offer an uninstall option.

Comment: @Twisty not a chance: this software was installed something like 3 years ago and I don't want to revert to that state!

Comment: @JimNim and magicandre1981 yes, I tried that option (forgot to mention it), but the installer don't have an option to modify/remove.

Comment: Why can't you just delete it?

Comment: @qasdfdsaq "CAN" yes, I can, but you probably know this should be avoided (specially in such "complicated packs" as Proteus which is actually a bunch of softwares and tools put together)

Comment: I see no reason why it should be avoided. Using uninstall tools like "Advanced Uninstaller PRO" is going to be worse in any case.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq why? After all, when we install a software it not only extract some files to a given folder, but it may change the registry and do other stuff in the system that a simple "delete the folder" will not revert. Tools such as AU-PRO and the own software uninstaller are aimed to remove such extra parts of the installation process.

Comment: Have you tried asking in the LabCenter support forum, or contacting their support?

Answer (score 0):

Run a Threat Scan with MalwareBytes which you can download from https://www.malwarebytes.org I believe it will identify it as a Potentially Unwanted Program (PUP) called PUP.Hacktool.Patcher and give you the opportunity to have MalwareBytes completely remove it for you.

Comment: The program in question is legit CAD software, so why do you think it'll be detected as PUP.Hacktool.Patcher?

Comment: Legit software provides standard methods for uninstalling.

Comment: I agree, and haven't used this one to know whether it doesn't provide an uninstaller at all or it's an issue specific to the OP's system. Regardless, just because there's no installer doesn't mean MBAM will automatically flag it as a PUP. Is the program specifically listed in the MBAM database as a PUP? Otherwise what are you basing your recommendation on?

Comment: There's a form of this virus included in a file called proteus.pro.7.6.sp4-patch.exe so it's worth scanning to see if the OP is infected. Anytime an uninstaller "disappears" or is hidden or removed, my first thought is to scan for malicious activity. Especially if re-running the original setup executable doesn't provide or restore the uninstall ability.

Comment: Ah, so you suspect that the OP used a potentially infected crack/patch? Scanning for malware is good advice but even if his system is infected I'd expect the patch (and any associated malware) to be detected and removed by MBAM, and not the legit program itself.

Comment: Yes, but if there's an infection, once it's removed, then the OP can use the legit installer to re-install and restore the ability to remove the application, or repair, or uninstall, etc.

Comment: Hopefully that'll work. Let's wait for the OP to report back.