# Windows 7 is not running properly and msconfig freezes all the time

Tags: windows-7, windows, freeze, msconfig

First, sorry for the "generic title"; I don't know how to name my problem.

I'm facing some difficulties to run my Windows 7 64 bit after I had some problems trying to change the apps to run at system start. In trying to solve [this uninstall issue](https://superuser.com/questions/930211/how-to-uninstall-software-that-doesnt-appear-in-programs-and-features-as-well-a), I started `msconfig` as suggested by one of the commentators to see if one my softwares are running in background. In doing this, I found that many apps were being run at startup without my consente. I started unchecking all of them and when I clicked "Apply", msconfig's screen freezed. After waiting for a while, I decided to close it forcefully and soon afterwards I noticed my internet (via wireless adapter) went down. Thinking it was something with the adapter, I try to open the Windows tool to check Network connectivity and the like and it freezed even before showing the window's contents. Noticing that Windows became unstable, I decided to close all running apps and restart the computer. When, though, the screen which says something like "Doing logoff" appeared, it stopped there and for 15 minutes or more Windows was stuck in this "Doing logoff" screen. Noticing that would stay so more than what I could accept, I shut down the computer by cutting its energy.

When I started my PC later, I discovered that Windows was running in the "classic style". I went to the Personalize screen and the Aero team was locked. Soon I noticed that not only that, but I was being unable to have access to the internet, my sound system was down na the Help Center wasn't being able to solve any of these problems. I restarted my PC, asked for a memory check, no problems found and Windows keeped running in this "partially functional state".

To finish, I decided to do some enter in the `msconfig` again and noticed some services I wanted were unchecked. After checking one of them and clicking "Apply", once again `msconfig` freezed. After closing it forcefully again, Windows started to fall appart once again: Explorer.exe went down and I wasn't able to reopen it, Control Panel was showing a error code each time I tried to call for it and no software would run. After hitting Ctrl+Alt+Del and asking for a system logoff, guess what? I found that same situation with the eternal "Doing logoff" screen.

I never encountered such a problem before and I fear my Windows is corrupted. Could anybody provide some suggestions on how could I restore my system back to normal? I'm glad for any help.

Comment: Boot in safe mode and use system restore? [Start System Restore from a command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-system-restore-command-prompt#1TC=windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Windows is corrupted. If even System Restore is not working, you can try  to use [SFC /scannow](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833/) to repair Windows.

Comment: It's better to make your answers "self-contained".  Rather than just mentioning a useful tool, include the basic instructions for how to solve the problem using the tool.  Otherwise, it's just a helpful hint instead of an actual solution, and would be more appropriate as a comment.